# SPAuditQuery.RowLimit and Paging in Auditing

Tags: paging, spaudit, row-limit

While trying to retrieve the Auditing entries programmatically, we pass the SPAuditQuery instance to the SPAudit.GetEntries method. The SPAuditQuery has a RowLimit property. Are there any limits (lower and upper) to the value assigned, similar to what we have in SPQuery, wherein it cannot exceed the threshold of 5000 set at the web application level? Can anyone please explain?

If we set this to some value, say 1000 and if there are more entries, how to get remaining entries? Is there any option? Does it have some asynchronous approach or some sort of paging? Please explain with code samples.

What if we don't specify the RowLimit. How many entries can be safely retrieved without crashing the application or causing performance issues?

Comment: I'm finding this to be incredibly unreliable. I ask for 2 items and it returns 1. I ask for 10 and it returns 10. I ask for 6 and it returns 4. It also doesn't always fill the HasMoreItems property. And it returns audit items for other items other than what i'm querying against